# High performance SQL tag search query with logical operations

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, relational-division

[How can I implement a boolean tag search in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602849/how-can-i-implement-a-boolean-tag-search-in-sql/602870#602870)
This question is about as close as I can find, but there's a few.

The only real solution I know is to generate a query like this through backend code and put it into SQL, But I imagine it is slow and I'm also wondering if there is any other way to do it (such as having one main query instead of multiple).

There's also solutions that probably use `IN` or something like:
[How to query data based on multiple 'tags' in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954934/how-to-query-data-based-on-multiple-tags-in-sql/38955049)

I cannot use the typical `GROUP BY HAVING COUNT` Solution as it cannot operate on the context of having a list of tags, as this user points out:  [Implementing a tag search with operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481769/implementing-a-tag-search-with-operands)

I should specify most of the existing solutions do not work as I'm looking for things that are capable of more complex queries such as parenthesis grouping and nested operands.

Schema is "Toxi" http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/

```
SELECT id AS post_id
FROM posts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS 'random')
AND NOT (
    EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS 'query') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS '1')
)
AND EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS '2') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS '3')
AND EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tags WHERE post IS post_id AND name IS 'racecar')
```

Comment: What is your question again. You have linked a couple of questions but I can't see why you can't use them.

Comment: @SalmanA I'm trying to find a faster or generally alternative way to do this, also some of them don't work at all.

Comment: Well, for faster you first need to establish if the current solution is slow. I will post an alternative though, if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GROUP BY HAVING COUNT` will work — and it will be fast, and versatile. Some examples:

```
CREATE TABLE tags(
    post_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    UNIQUE KEY (post_id, name)
);

INSERT INTO tags(post_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'foo'),
(1, 'bar'),

(2, 'foo'),

(3, 'bar'),

(4, 'baz'),

(5, 'foo'),
(5, 'bar'),
(5, 'meh');

-- posts tagged foo AND bar
-- returns 1, 5
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) = 2;

-- posts tagged foo OR bar
-- returns 1, 2, 3, 5
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) > 0;

-- posts tagged (foo AND bar) OR (baz)
-- returns 1, 4, 5
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) = 2
OR     COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('baz') THEN 1 END) = 1;

-- posts tagged (foo AND bar) AND (no other tags)
-- returns 1
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) = 2
AND    COUNT(*) = 2;

-- posts tagged (foo OR bar) AND NOT (meh)
-- returns 1, 2, 3
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('meh') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f7e8592adef4a691f26060fa05f59a5c)

---

Converting an expression such as `tag1 AND tag2 OR tag3` to the corresponding `HAVING COUNT` is not covered in my answer but the five examples should be sufficient.

Comment: -- posts tagged foo AND bar
SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS for_testing
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('foo', 'bar') THEN 1 END) = 2
AND NOT (COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('tes') THEN 1 END) = 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('bru') THEN 1 END) = 0 )

Comment: INSERT INTO tags(post_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'foo'),
(1, 'bar'),
(2, 'foo'),
(2, 'bar'),
(2, 'tes'),
(2, 'bru')

This seems to work too with grouping, thank you.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that case. Basically `AND COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN ('tes', 'bru') THEN 1 END) = 0` can be used to exclude posts where they contain tes or bru or both. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema prep**

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    subj nvarchar(50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE tags (
    post INT,
    name nvarchar(50)
)
GO
```

**Data Prep**

```
INSERT INTO posts (subj) VALUES ('post1')
INSERT INTO posts (subj) VALUES ('post2')
INSERT INTO posts (subj) VALUES ('post3')

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'food')
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 'spicy')

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 'spicy')
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 'recipe')

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'food')
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'spicy')
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 'sweet')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH Aggregated_Tags AS (
    SELECT
        post,
        STRING_AGG(name, ',') AS name
    FROM tags
    GROUP BY post
)
SELECT post
FROM Aggregated_Tags
WHERE 
    (name LIKE '%food%' AND name LIKE '%spicy%' AND name NOT LIKE '%sweet%')
    OR (name LIKE '%recipe%')
GROUP BY post
```

If i understood you correctly you are searching for something like this. The key here is to aggregate the tags per post in order to eliminate generating multiple select queries. This solution is not complete but i believe is a good start.